# Representing a fixpoint in a head-normal lambda calculus AST

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Consider the following normalized term representation, obtained during type checking:

```
data Normal a
  = Neutral (Neutral a)
  | Type
  | Pi (Normal a) (Normal (Maybe a))
  | Abstract (Normal (Maybe a))

data Neutral a
  = Variable a
  | Apply (Neutral a) (Normal a)
```

I would like to be able to represent a fixpoint within this framework, or at least in a way that preserves its head-normal property, which is very convenient for implementing substitution and definitional equality.

At first, I thought of using a fixpoint combinator defined in the calculus itself.  The Y combinator is out of the question, though, as with this term representation I cannot apply a lambda to a lambda.  The Z combinator is close to what I want, but assumes that the result is to be a function.

If I were simply doing graph reduction, I would tie the knot with Haskell itself, leading to a lazy infinite syntax tree.  However, as this is being used for a dependent type checker, I need to be able to test for definitional equality on terms - it would get caught in an infinite loop this way.

Comment: Won't (arbitrary) fixed points make you lose the normalization property? In Agda/Coq there's a termination checker to prevent that, essentially limiting recursion to structural (higher-order) induction. Without inductive types, I'm not sure how to guarantee termination and fixpoints in an easy way.

Comment: This is only for the normalized calculus, i.e. type checking, termination checking have already happened.